# Swift Push UIViewController

Tags: swift

В Сториборде есть `UIViewController` который управляется `UINavigationController`, его `Identifier("vcDen")`. 
 Он на Objective C, в нем есть метод который принимает `NSString -(void)setText:(NSString*)text`.

Как с контроллера на swift сделать push этого контроллера и передать его методу какой нить текст `NSString`?

Такая схема не работает ! ! !

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("vcDen") as UIViewController

[vc setText:"gjhgjgjgjhg"]

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: вообще не работает или текст не передается?

Comment: уже решил...ниже, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

значит когда мы подключаем файл свифта в си проект, у нас появляется файл моста ObjCProject-Bridging-Header.h так вот в него необходиму сделать обычный СИшный импорт #import "meClass_C.h" и далее создание объекта я сделал в свифте вот так

@IBAction func btnClick(sender: AnyObject) {

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("meClass_C") as! meClass_C
```

// это создает объект класса написанного на Си(на всякий)

//          let myObjClass:meClass_C = meClass_C()

//           myObjClass.sendText("Den")

```
    vc.sendText("привет")// у этого Си класса есть метод sendText, который принимает текст и передает далее там
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

}
```